# BQ Ubuntu Pad media Devices Access Solved

Tags: usb, mount, ubuntu-touch, sd-card

Hi I just wanted to share what I have found on how to connect your USB or SD card to your Ubuntu BQ Aquarius pad. Since I have searched most of the post on Internet on how to access it and haven't found any information regarding connecting media or file transfer. Most of the posts were regarding on how to mount usb or sd card. I found that you don't need to mount your SD/usb, all you need is to connect the device, install terminal from Ubuntu software center. Once you run the terminal you can access your media devices in **root** directory under **(media)** folder */media/phablet/"STORE N GO"*. All you need to do is copy your desired files form that folder to your **(home)** folder which is located in /home/phablet/ and you all set. Hope this was helpfull.